# Set checkbox value from database

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a database field is_enabled - which set to either 'Yes' or 'No'.

Following checkbox will have to set as checked if the db field is 'Yes'.

```
<input name="enab" type="checkbox"> <label>Enabled Status: </label>
```

JQuery:

```
$('[name=enab]').val(values.enab);
```

Anyone please help.

Comment: `$('[name=enab]').prop('chekced', values.enab=='Yes');`

Comment: $('[name=enab]').prop('**checked**', values.enab=='Yes'); - spell mistake